# JDBC4 insert date "0001-01-01"

Tags: java, sql-server, date, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to insert "0001-01-01" as a value into a **date** field by using Java `PreparedStatement`.

But it throws exception when I tried this:

```
String sql = "insert into mytable values(?)"
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);   
ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("0001-01-01"));
ps.executeUpdate(); // throws exceptions here.
```

The error is :

> The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type datetime. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.

- If I don't use PreparedStatement, I can insert "0001-01-01". However,
  prepare statement seems not allow me to insert this value.
- It will work if I inserted "1969-01-01" instead of "0001-01-01".

Any ideas?

**Updates:**
Here are more info that might be needed.

1. we use sql server 2012.
2. we have to use "0001-01-01" because these values were already there. I am changing some very very old codes to use prepare statement. So I have to insert the same values in the same functionality.

**Updates 2:**

- We are using "**date**" datatype, not "**datetime**" datatype.
  Based on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx, "0001-01-01" is not out of range for "date" field.

In addition, I am able to insert "0001-01-01" to the date field without using prepare statement. i.e.

```
   String sql = "insert into mytable values('0001-01-01')"
   java.sql.Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
   statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

So it is not sql server's problem or db field's problem.

Comment: Try using another date to represent empty date such as 01-01-1900

Comment: Have a quick look at the source code of `.valueOf(...)` ;)

Comment: Which JDBC driver JAR are you using? jTDS or Microsoft?  And which version?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with version 4.2 of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver jar (sqljdbc42.jar). I could insert that date into `date` and `datetime2` columns, and inserting it into a `datetime` column gave a different error message.  I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express instead of SQL Server 2012; I don't know what difference that makes.

Comment: I am not sure which version do I use as I do not know how to find out. I just downloaded sqljdbc42.jar and try with it. It produces the same error.

Comment: *"I am not sure which version do I use as I do not know how to find out."* - If, for example, your `Connection` object (as created by `DriverManager.getConnection`) is named `conn` then try `conn.getMetaData().getDriverVersion()`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward "version 4.2" is not the version of the driver, but the JDBC specification version that the driver supports.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I ran Gord Thompson's Java code to find out the driver version of `sqljdbc42.jar`.  It returned `4.2.6420.100`.  So I'm inclined to say 4.2 is the version of the driver and also of the JDBC spec it implements.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes, but "version 4.x" is not enough to tell us if the driver version (actually "revision", I suppose) is current. For example, my old test box is currently using version "4.1.5504" whereas the most recent version of the JDBC 4.1 driver for SQL Server is "4.1.5605".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the different suitable JDBC driver.